# plt.savefig through a loop not working

Tags: pandas, for-loop, matplotlib, time-series

I have already seen that there are questions with similar topics, but the answers did not work for my problem.
I am trying to loop through a list of `dataframes` (a timeseries) and save one figure with four subplots for each dataframe. The code and the loop works fine (all plots are displayed) until I add the line with plt.savefig. I am using Phyton 3.6 in Spyder 3.1.4.

When I add the plt.savefig command only the first plot in the loop is displayed and I get the error message:

```
filename_or_obj = open(filename_or_obj, 'wb')

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

Here is some test data and the code

```
#non-fancy test data
dates = pd.date_range(start='2008-01-01 00:30:00',end='2018-01-01 00:00:00',freq='30T')
data1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(175344, 4)),columns=list('ABCD'))
data2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(175344, 4)),columns=list('ABCD'))
d1={'col_1': datetest, 'col_2': data1['D'],'col_3':data1['D'],'col_4': data1['D'],'col_5': data1['D'] }
d2={'col_1': datetest, 'col_2': data2['D'],'col_3':data2['D'],'col_4': data2['D'],'col_5': data2['D'] }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2) 

#make a list
t_list=[df1,df2]

#start the loop for plotting
for year in t_list:
      ax1 = plt.subplot(411)
      ax2 = plt.subplot(412)
      ax3 = plt.subplot(413)
      ax4 = plt.subplot(414)
      ax1.plot_date(year.col_1,year.col_2)
      ax2.plot_date(year.col_1,year.col_2)
      ax3.plot_date(year.col_1,year.col_2)
      ax4.plot_date(year.col_1,year.col_4)
      plt.savefig('{}.png'.format(year))
      plt.close()
```

I have also tried `'lala'+str(year)+'.png'` without success. When I choose a static name that does not change, the last sublopt will be saved to a file. I read some posts with related topics but I could not find the one that could help me with my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`year` is a DataFrame. You cannot format a dataframe into a string that is acceptable as filename.

Use something like

```
for i, year in enumerate(t_list):
    # ...
    plt.savefig('lala'+str(i)+'.png')
```

instead.